# Get the properties of the current network connection

Tags: c#, networking, network-programming

How do you determine or examine the connection profile of the current network connection (if any)?

Specifically, I need to determine if the current connection is to a private or public network, and from there determine whether network discovery is turned on or off.

It seems like this information is readily available in a Windows Store app via the [Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation.GetConnectionProfiles()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.connectivity.networkinformation.getconnectionprofiles.aspx) or [NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.connectivity.networkinformation.getinternetconnectionprofile.aspx) functions, **but this is a standard desktop app** that must run on Win 7 and Server 2008 as well as Win 8 and Server 2012.

[Enumerating the NICs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getallnetworkinterfaces.aspx) on a machine is not a problem, but this doesn't solve my issue - I need to get the properties of the *connection*, not the *physical device*.

Is there an inbuilt way to do this with the .Net framework? Alternatively can it be done with WMI? Or as a crude alternative, can it be done by invoking the `netsh` command (although this seems to depend on the [dot3svc](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc727725%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) and/or [wlansvc](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730957.aspx) services to be running)?

Comment: Does this help at all? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578480/unable-to-obtain-profile-of-connected-network-in-vista-7

Comment: @JunWeiLee Thanks, it doesn't directly help. That is a code snippet that users the [Managed Wifi API](http://managedwifi.codeplex.com/) which wraps the [Native Wifi API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms705969.aspx).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [Network List Manager API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965312%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for that purpose, to use it from C# import Network List Manager Type Library.

Then you must enumerate all connected networks, because there can be more than one, for example right now I am connected to internet and VPN. Then for all connected networks call [GetCategory()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370780%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API, it returns [NLM_NETWORK_CATEGORY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370800%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (private, public or domain).

Here is the sample code (add using NETWORKLIST in use clauses) :

```
  var manager = new NetworkListManager();
  var connectedNetworks = manager.GetNetworks(NLM_ENUM_NETWORK.NLM_ENUM_NETWORK_CONNECTED).Cast<INetwork>();
  foreach (var network in connectedNetworks)
  {
    Console.Write(network.GetName() + " ");
    var cat = network.GetCategory();
    if (cat == NLM_NETWORK_CATEGORY.NLM_NETWORK_CATEGORY_PRIVATE)
      Console.WriteLine("[PRIVATE]");
    else if (cat == NLM_NETWORK_CATEGORY.NLM_NETWORK_CATEGORY_PUBLIC)
      Console.WriteLine("[PUBLIC]");
    else if (cat == NLM_NETWORK_CATEGORY.NLM_NETWORK_CATEGORY_DOMAIN_AUTHENTICATED)
      Console.WriteLine("[DOMAIN]");
  }      
  Console.ReadKey();
```

For this to work one must add reference to COM Network List 1.0 Type Library, like this:

[image: adding COM Network List 1.0 Type library]

For Network Discovery you have to use Firewall API and reference COM library NetFwTypeLib and get [INetFwProfile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365327%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for active profile, then in services there are File sharing, Network Discovery and Remote Desktop services, and there is a bool flag if these are Enabled. Here is the example code : (just to warn you I didn't use below code in production I was just exploring this API)

```
  Type objectType = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(new Guid("{304CE942-6E39-40D8-943A-B913C40C9CD4}"));
  var man = Activator.CreateInstance(objectType) as INetFwMgr;
  /// get current profile 
  INetFwProfile prof = man.LocalPolicy.CurrentProfile;
  Console.WriteLine("Current profile ");
  ShowProfileServices(prof);
```

And the method that shows profile services.

```
private static void ShowProfileServices(INetFwProfile prof)
{
  var services = prof.Services.Cast<INetFwService>();
  var sharing = services.FirstOrDefault(sc => sc.Name == "File and Printer Sharing");
  if (sharing != null)
    Console.WriteLine(sharing.Name + " Enabled : " + sharing.Enabled.ToString());
  else
    Console.WriteLine("No sharing service !");

  var discovery = services.FirstOrDefault(sc => sc.Name == "Network Discovery");

  if (discovery != null)
    Console.WriteLine(discovery.Name + " Enabled : " + discovery.Enabled.ToString());
  else
    Console.WriteLine("No network discovery service !");

  var remoteDesktop = services.FirstOrDefault(sc => sc.Name == "Remote Desktop");
  if (remoteDesktop != null)
    Console.WriteLine(remoteDesktop.Name + " Enabled : " + remoteDesktop.Enabled.ToString());
  else
    Console.WriteLine("No remote desktop service !");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it solves part of my problem (I'm not sure the "network discovery" setting is easily obtainable).

Comment: oh, didn't see this, I played somewhat with firewall API's and there is a way trough that, I will update my answer

Comment: Great answer, it was everything I needed :)

Comment: I would recommend keeping `Embed Interop Types` set to true though. You can avoid needing to change it by simply removing "Class" from `var manager = new NetworkListManagerClass();`... so that line should instead be `var manager = new NetworkListManager();`. Then you can minimize the dependency introduced by this COM reference.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My Windows language is Turkish and sc.Name is "Dosya ve Yazıcı paylaşımı" :) 
So prefer sc.Type == NET_FW_SERVICE_TYPE_.NET_FW_SERVICE_FILE_AND_PRINT

Comment: sharing is not null and sharing.Name returned properly. But when i try to access sharing.Enabled throw "An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'" E_UNEXPECTED

i cant find any resolve. Why i get this exception?

Application and VS have Administration Privileges

Comment: sorry don't have clue why this is happening, for me it worked properly

Comment: `'NetworkListManagerClass' is inaccessible due to its protection level` How do I fix this?

Comment: @Dan hmm, it's been almost 10 years from my answer, I tried to run this code and you must add reference to COM Network List Manager 1.0 Type library and change NetworkListManagerClass to NetworkListManager. I updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is super old, but I faced this problem recently - how to get Network Category (private or public) in C# using Windows.Network.Connectivity from Windows Runtime API.

There is almost everything related to networking but I could not find the Network Category.

The solution is NetworkTypes enum.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.connectivity.networktypes?view=winrt-22000

Simply check if returned types has flag PrivateNetwork. If yes - then is't private, if not - it's public.

Example code below:

```
var adapters = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
var upNetworkInterfaces = adapters.Where(x =>
    x.Supports(NetworkInterfaceComponent.IPv4) &&
    x.NetworkInterfaceType is NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet or NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211);
foreach (var adapter in upNetworkInterfaces)
{
    var hostname = NetworkInformation.GetHostNames()
        .FirstOrDefault(x =>
            x.IPInformation != null &&
            string.Equals(x.IPInformation.NetworkAdapter.NetworkAdapterId.ToString(),
                adapter.Id.Replace("{", string.Empty).Replace("}", string.Empty),
                StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

    if (hostname is not null)
    {
        var networkTypes = hostname.IPInformation.NetworkAdapter.NetworkItem.GetNetworkTypes();
        var privateNetwork = networkTypes.HasFlag(NetworkTypes.PrivateNetwork)
            ? NetworkAccessibilityLevel.Private
            : NetworkAccessibilityLevel.Public;
    }
}
```